# Lots of error with latest Flutter dev release

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm not sure what version I was using which was working properly (but prior to Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.86), but since I switched from stable to dev channel to work on a web project and I got a load of errors..mostly with `js: ^0.6.1+1`, `intl: ^0.16.0` and `firebase: ^7.3.2 packages. Now, I solved the intl` depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0, intl 0.17.0 is required.`by overriding it with`intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2` but I still got a load of errors from js and firebase packages, which I use for web as official packages don't have a web counterpart quite yet. Do you know if it's just some packages not being ready for the latest Flutter version or something else needs to be fixed?
As always thank you very much for the help.
Errors:

```
Invalid depfile: /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/Flutter project/fixit_shop_flutter/.dart_tool/flutter_build/120221be81f1d8dd9be87e1783094685/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/Flutter project/fixit_shop_flutter/.dart_tool/flutter_build/120221be81f1d8dd9be87e1783094685/kernel_snapshot.d
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/top_level.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
       ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';
^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart:306:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart:340:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart:345:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((e) => _idTokenChangedController.addError(e));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart:164:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((update) => jsify(transactionUpdate(dartify(update))));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart:166:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var onCompleteWrap = allowInterop(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart:301:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var callbackWrap = allowInterop((database_interop.DataSnapshotJsImpl data,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart:325:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    jsObject.once(eventType, allowInterop(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart:402:22: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DataSnapshot'.
 - 'DataSnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var actionWrap = allowInterop((d) => action(DataSnapshot.getInstance(d)));
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart:72:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart:75:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart:87:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart:97:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((_) => null);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart:98:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/storage.dart:320:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((storage_interop.UploadTaskSnapshotJsImpl data) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/storage.dart:324:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/storage.dart:325:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var onCompletion = allowInterop(() {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/top_level.dart:196:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (js.hasProperty(error, 'message')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/top_level.dart:197:19: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    var message = js.getProperty(error, 'message');
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:29:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'firestore') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:30:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'id') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:31:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'parent')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:37:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'latitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:38:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'longitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:44:15: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  var proto = util.getProperty(jsObject, '__proto__');
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:46:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'toDate') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:47:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toMillis')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:52:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'isEqual') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:53:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toBase64')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:67:24: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    map[key] = dartify(util.getProperty(jsObject, key));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:91:17: Error: Method not found: 'newObject'.
    var jsMap = util.newObject();
                ^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:93:7: Error: Method not found: 'setProperty'.
      util.setProperty(jsMap, key, jsify(value));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:116:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    return allowInterop(dartObject);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:124:5: Error: Method not found: 'callMethod'.
    util.callMethod(jsObject, method, args);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:139:19: Error: Method not found: 'promiseToFuture'.
    value = await util.promiseToFuture(thenable);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:141:9: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
    if (util.hasProperty(e, 'code')) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:152:27: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
  return PromiseJsImpl<S>(allowInterop((
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:165:5: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    allowInterop(c.completeError);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:173:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get code => util.getProperty(_source, 'code');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:176:25: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get message => util.getProperty(_source, 'message');
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:179:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get name => util.getProperty(_source, 'name');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:182:32: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  Object get serverResponse => util.getProperty(_source, 'serverResponse');
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/utils.dart:185:23: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get stack => util.getProperty(_source, 'stack');
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart:105:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Firestore'.
 - 'Firestore' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var updateFunctionWrap = allowInterop((transaction) =>
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart:306:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((firestore_interop.DocumentSnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart:445:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((firestore_interop.QuerySnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart:449:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart:775:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.
 - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((s) => callback(DocumentSnapshot.getInstance(s)));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.3/lib/src/interop/js_interop.dart:17:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'toDateString')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart:23:41: Error: Getter not found: 'window'.
  final String navigatorPlatform = html.window.navigator.platform?.toLowerCase() ?? '';
                                        ^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart:43:12: Error: Getter not found: 'window'.
  if (html.window.matchMedia('only screen and (pointer: fine)').matches) {
           ^^^^^^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Info: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Info: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Info: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Info: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Info: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Info: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Info: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Info: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Info: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Info: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Info: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Support for empty structs is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Use Opaque instead.
class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Info: Support for using non-constant type arguments 'T' in this FFI API is deprecated and will be removed in the next stable version of Dart. Rewrite the code to ensure that type arguments are compile time constants referring to a valid native type.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:599:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:738:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:554:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:180:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
<asynchronous suspension>



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Use stable channel 1.22.2 might you will not get error

Comment: But the stable channel doesn't build for web, right?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ali.gh2236/how-to-enable-flutter-web-on-the-stable-channel-f4f1762c79cb refer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. It of course was due to the update of the `cloud_firestore` package. As it now has the web version which conflicts with `firebase` package. The latest compatible version is `cloud_firestore: 0.14.0` and until remote config will also have a web version I'm stuck using `firebase` package for the web version of my apps..

Also the Firebase initialisation method differs:
new not working:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

  return FutureBuilder(
    future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasError){

        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
          return MaterialApp(

...
```

old working:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    return MaterialApp(
...
```

Hope it helps others as Firebase is always breaking the code with almost any update..

Answer (score 0):

I face similar error flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_platform_web.dart
import 'dart:html' not found
i figure out i did not enable web for my project and a package im using is for web usage that cause the problem its either you init web build in your project or figure out which package is causing the issue

try `flutter create .`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).